# Can I use two inferred clauses to get the empty set?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In resolution can I use two ***inferred*** clauses to reach the empty set?

Consider this set of clauses:
$\{ p \lor q,\neg p \lor r, \neg p \lor \neg r, p \lor \neg q\}$

\begin{align*}
\quad  p \lor q\quad &|\quad p \lor \neg q  \ \rightarrow \quad p \\
\quad  p  \quad &|\quad \neg p \lor r \ \rightarrow \ \quad r \\
\quad  \neg p \lor \neg r\quad &|\quad r \quad  \ \rightarrow \quad \neg p \\
\quad  \neg p \quad &|\quad p    \ \rightarrow \quad \varnothing
\end{align*}

In this case I infered both $\neg p$ and $p$, can I use resolution on them? Or can I only resolve with the given clauses?

I'm also a bit confused on why I can't infer the empty clause from: $\{p \lor q, \neg p \lor \neg q \}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In this case I infered both ¬p and p, can I use resolution on them? "

Yes, you can.

"I'm also a bit confused on why I can't infer the empty clause from: {p∨q,¬p∨¬q}"

Resolution, in propositional logic, is the disjunction of all literals except those two literals which complement each other, and thus resolve into the rest of the formula.  With (p∨q) and (¬p∨¬q) you can resolve to (q∨¬q) (cancelling p) or (p∨¬p).  Either way though you get a tautology.  This is the exact opposite of resolving to the empty set.  Thus, if you could infer to the empty clause, you could get a different truth value than what resolution can actually yield in such a case.